# Crossfire/Unify - Change Settings in TX and in OSD

Tags: crossfire, crossfire-nano, tbs-unify-pro32-nano

I have a Crossfire Nano RX and a Unify Pro32 Nano VTX.  I'm using the CRSF setting and wiring to allow the LUA script in the radio to change the settings in the VTX (*power, band, channel, pitmode on/off*).  I'd like to keep this functionality, but also be able to change VTX settings in the Betaflight OSD as well.  Is this possible?

Summary:

1. I'd like to keep the ability to configure the VTX via my radio
2. I'd like to add the ability to configure the VTX via Betaflight OSD

Comment: This is very similar to this question https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/257/how-do-i-set-up-lua-scripts-on-my-opentx-radio/261#261 and the answer there should help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s not exactly what I’m looking for. I know all about SA, but I want the SA functionality while also being able to control the VTX with my Crossfire Radio. Maybe I’m overthinking it because I realize that with FrSky, I could do both with SA. I’m new to Crossfire and I was unable to do both after a few attempts.

Comment: I think if you are using the direct crossfire wiring to the VTX then you will not be able to use the FC to control the VTX via the OSD as well. If you want to use the betaflight LUA scripts on the radio and have the VTX SA connection to the FC then both OSD and LUA will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, you cannot use both. When you set the vtx up for lua in the radio, you change the communication protocol from SA to CRSF. You also remove the SA wire from the FC and move it to the Rx channel 1. So having just done this twice, it seems you get one or the other.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since I've come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s called SmartAudio.

I don’t know exactly how you have your VTX wired up, but you can use a spare UART on your FC and then set it up in the ports tab in Betaflight.

Then you can configure your settings in the VTX tab in Betaflight.

Comment: Thanks. I’m fully aware of SmartAudio. However, it seems that with Crossfire, if I want to be able to control the VTX via my radio, I have to abandon SmartAudio and use the CRSF RX/TX signals instead - where the control signals go to the RX from the VTX instead of SmartAudio going to FC from VTX.

Comment: @Schome1 oh that’s odd - I’m not sure then - sorry.